# Order items in a mysql table where the order is conditional on the value of a particular [mutable] column

Tags: mysql

Hypothetical example:  you have a table called HOUSES and you want to display each row in order of the last updated.
-Most recent first, least recent last.
-you also want to order them with the unsold first, and all of the sold stock last.

-The administrator must also be able to make a change from unsold to sold, and have that change drop an item to the bottom with the other sold.  AND BE ABLE TO MAKE a manual change to the display order of a particular house if so desired.

How should I do this?  These are the columns I have to work with:

```
  -ID (which can be used to order them by date added i suppose), 
  -PRICE (vals are: the price if unsold or "SOLD" if sold)
  -DISP_ORDER (an integer field with the true display order)
```

Comment: Just an FYI: I would not store price as some sort of character / string representation.  I would create one additional bit field called "Sold" if its checked it sold otherwise its on the market.  Use price for what the asking price is (decimal value).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change these columns, they are already there by the previous programmer who put them there.  I don't want to create a mess and change them.

Comment: fair enough....that will definately bite down the road.

Comment: Do you have a `last_update` column? Because `id` can be (not accurate but) fair enough compromise for `date_inserted` but when a row is updated, the `id` does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        ID, PRICE, DISP_ORDER,
        CASE WHEN PRICE = 'SOLD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS soldOrder,
        CASE WHEN DISP_ORDER > 0 THEN DISP_ORDER ELSE -ID END AS customOrder
    FROM HOUSES
) AS q
ORDER BY
   soldOrder, customOrder
```

The inner-query builds two custom sort columns. `soldOrder` will make all sold-items value 1 and all non-sold items value 0. The `customOrder` column will use the `DISP_ORDER` value if it's set, otherwise it will use `-ID` (to get the "date created in descending order" implementation).
The outer-query will select all of the fields and order by `sortOrder` first (placing all unsold items at the top, sold at the bottom) and then ordering each of the two halves by their `customOrder` values (`DISP_ORDER` values first followed by all items in most-recent-change-first order).